# tempo mode elisp function acting on region

Tags: function, variables, emacs

I am trying to set up a tempo-template that when called with a C-u prefix is to surround the region with the tags \begin{environment} and \end{environment} and insert the tag \item at the beginning of each line in the region. However it gives as 'save-excursion: Args out of range: 2247, 2312' error.

```
(require 'tempo)
(setq tempo-interactive t)

(tempo-define-template "env"
'("\\begin{" (p "Environment: " environment) "}" > n>
r> n>
"\\end{" (s environment) "}" > n
(save-excursion
(narrow-to-region start end)
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward "^" nil t) (replace-match "\\item " nil t))
(widen)
))
"env"
"Insert a LaTeX environment.")

(defun item (start end)
(interactive "r")
(save-excursion 
(narrow-to-region start end)
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward "^" nil t) (replace-match "\\item " nil t))
(widen)
))
```

The item function by itself works fine on a region. I tried calling the elisp function item in the tempo-template:

```
(tempo-define-template "env"
'("\\begin{" (p "Environment: " environment) "}" > n>
r> n>
"\\end{" (s environment) "}" > n
(item point-min point-max)
)
"env"
"Insert a LaTeX environment.")
```

However, this gives a 'eval: Symbol's value as variable is void: point-min' error.
Any pointers to fix the problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`point-min` and `point-max` are functions, so you should call them as in `(item (point-min) (point-max))`:

```
(tempo-define-template
 "env"
 '("\\begin{" (p "Environment: " environment) "}" > n>
   r> n>
   "\\end{" (s environment) "}" > n
   (item (point-min) (point-max))) ; HERE
 "env"
 "Insert a LaTeX environment.")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Deokhwan Kim: Thanks for looking into this. Using (item (point-min) (point-max)) in the template does the replacement over the entire buffer. With (item (region-beginning) (region-end)) the modified template now works:

```
(require 'tempo)
(setq tempo-interactive t)

(tempo-define-template
 "list"
'("\\begin{" (p "List environment: " environment) "}" > n>
r> (item (region-beginning) (region-end)) 
"\\end{" (s environment) "}" > n>
)
"list"
"Insert a LaTeX list environment.")

(defun item (start end)
(interactive "r")
(save-excursion
(narrow-to-region start end)
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward "^[^\\]" (point-max) t) (replace-match "\\item " nil t))
(widen)
))
```

Comment: To restore any original narrowing, it would be better to write `(save-excursion (save-restriction (narrow-to-region ...) (goto-char ...) (while ...)))` in place of `(save-excursion (narrow-to-region ...) (goto-char ...) (while ...) (widen))`.